# A group of order $p^n, p $prime, and $[G: C_G(x)] \leq p$ for all $x \in G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm working through "The Theory of Finite Groups" by Kurzweil and Stellmacher.  I'm struggling with section 1.5, and I need help on Exercise 3:

Let $|G|=p^n$, $p$ a prime, and let $[G:C_G(x)]\leq p$ for all $x \in G$.

(a) $C_G(x) \unlhd G$ for all $x \in G$

(b) $G'\leq Z(G)$

(c)$|G'| \leq p$.

Defns:
$C_G(x)=${$y \in G | yx=xy$}

$Z(G)=${$x \in G | a^{-1}xa=x$ for all $a \in G$}

$G'=${$[x, y]  | x, y \in G$}

$[x, y] = x^{-1}y^{-1}xy$

As far as I've gotten:

Proof for part (a):

By Lagrange's Theorem, $[G:C_G(x)] | p^n$, so since $[G:C_G(x)]\leq p$ we must have $[G:C_G(x)]=1$ or $[G:C_G(x)]=p$.
If $[G:C_G(x)]=1$, then $C_G(x) = G$, so obviously $C_G(x) \unlhd G$.

If  $[G:C_G(x)]=p$ then by Lagrange's Theorem, $|G| = [G:C_G(x)]|C_G(x)| $ so$ p^n=|G| = [G:C_G(x)]|C_G(x)|=[G:C_G(x)]p$,

then $|C_G(x)|=p^{n-1}$.  Then $C_G(x)$ is a Sylow p-subgroup, and by Sylow's theorem, $n_p$ divides $1$, so $C_G(x)$ is the unique Sylow p-subgroup, so $C_G(x) \unlhd G$.

I'm stuck for parts (b) and (c).

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You're solution is completely wrong. What is the definition of a $p$-Sylow subgroup? If $|G|=p^rm$ when $p$ is a prime, $m$ is a natural number and $p$ does not divide $m$ then a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $G$ is a subgroup of order $p^r$. In your case $|G|=p^n$, so the $p$-Sylow subgroups are subgroups of order $p^n$ and not of order $p^{n-1}$. Hence the only $p$-Sylow subgroup of $G$ is $G$ itself.

I'll give you a hint about part $a$: try to prove that if $G$ is any finite group and $p$ is the least prime which divides $|G|$ then any subgroup of index $p$ is normal in $G$. That will give you the solution to part $a$.

And by the way, the definition of $G'$ should be $\langle \{[x,y]: x,y\in G\}\rangle$. It's not just the set of commutators, it is the group that is a generated by commutators.

I'll also give you a hint on part $b$ after you finish with part $a$. If $N\triangleleft G$ then $G'\leq N$ iff $G/N$ is abelian. Well, when you finish part $a$ you will know every centralizer is normal in $G$ and its quotient group has order $1$ or $p$. What can you conclude?